# Why does my prime number code time out on CodeWars?

Tags: python

so pretty straight forward, I had to write a code to check if a number if Prime or not. Code tested on Jupyter Notebook and works PERFECTLY. But whenever I put it in CodeWars, it passes the initial tests but later on when I submit the attempt, it times out, saying that the code may be "inefficient". Does anyone have an insight as to why this might be happening? Here is the code:

```
def is_prime(num):
    mylist = []
    if num != 1 and num > 0:
        for number in range(1,num+1):
            if num % number == 0:
                mylist.append(number)
            else:
                pass
        
        if len(mylist)>2:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Checking to see if _all_ numbers upto the given number divide into it _is an inefficient way_ to test if a number is prime. For one, you could simply check the numbers upto its square root. [There are other even more efficient tests for primality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).

Answer (score 0):

For large numbers, your time to compute will take too long.

I suggest looking more into the properties of prime numbers and reevaluating your code.

Ex: [Properties of Prime Numbers](https://byjus.com/maths/prime-numbers/)!

Answer (score 0):

can you try this and see how it works in CodeWars.

for num in range(1,7):
if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,num)):

```
    print('Prime' , num)
```